# How to compare metrics between two large texts - cosine, Jaccard similarities, Sim_MinEdit (Sim_String) and Sim_Simple in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on text analytics project comparing two different reports at a time and saving the results into pandas data frame.

I was able to get cosine and jacard similarities, but need to be sure that I get the right measures. As arguments I use file names that are located at the given folder.

For the cosine_sim I use the following code:

```
import re, math
from collections import Counter

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

def text_to_vector(text):
     words = WORD.findall(text)
     return Counter(words)

def get_cosine(file1, file2):
    t1 = file(Input_path+'/'+file1).read().replace('\n',' ')
    t2 = file(Input_path+'/'+file2).read().replace('\n',' ')    
    vec1 = text_to_vector(t1)
    vec2 = text_to_vector(t2)

    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])
    sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)
    if not denominator:
       return 0.0
    else:
       return float(numerator) / denominator
```

For Jaccard I got the following:

```
def get_jaccard(file1, file2):
    t1 = file(Input_path+'/'+file1).read().replace('\n',' ')
    t2 = file(Input_path+'/'+file2).read().replace('\n',' ')    
    vec1 = text_to_vector(t1)
    vec2 = text_to_vector(t2)

    numerator = len(set(vec1.keys()).intersection(set(vec2.keys())))
    denominator = float(len(set(vec1.keys())) + len(set(vec2.keys())) -numerator) 

    if not denominator:
       return 0.0
    else:
       return float(numerator) / denominator
```

The results work fine on small string examples, but I'm not sure if they are correct on big test files, especially Jaccard as my results are a bit different from distance.jaccard (I use lists to feed it, not dictionaries)

Regarding the other metrics, please confirm that sim_simple can be calculated by using the following:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(file1, file2):
    s1 = file(Input_path+'/'+file1).read().replace('\n',' ')
    s2 = file(Input_path+'/'+file2).read().replace('\n',' ')  
    list1 = list(set(text_to_list(s1)))
    list2 = list(set(text_to_list(s2)))
    return SequenceMatcher(None, list1, list2).ratio()
```

I am not sure about Sim_string (minimum edit). It is like Levenshtein distance, but on word level and I am not sure if distance.levenshtein would help.

Could you please help me to test the metrics I got and advise what to use for Sim_string.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Do you have a constraint that limits you from using an existing library like sklearn, etc. for this purpose? It has text similarity functions and quite a few examples available on the net

Comment: I do. I can't force my client thousands miles away to install any extra libraries.

Comment: Excuse me, @ibarant, but WHAT exactly is ```sim_simple```? Is this metric mentioned in some books or articles? Or is it implemented in some public library? Same for ```Sim_string```.

Comment: I completely agree with your question as I got this metric request from the client and did not find anything "in some books or articles". That's why I asked around. Discussing with the client, we agreed that it will be 1 - (number of words needed to be added / remove to make the files the same)/ total number of words in both texts)

Comment: @David, the only explanation I got is the following:

“The third similarity measure we employ is called Sim_MinEdit (also known as Sim_String) and is computed by counting the smallest number of operations required to transform one document into the other. In the same textual examples DA, DB, and DC as
above, transforming DA to DB only requires adding the word “worldwide”, while transforming DA to DC requires deleting 3 words “demand”, “to”, and “increase” and adding 3 words “weakness”, “in”, “sales”.

Comment: Just to clarify, DA: We expect demand to increase.
DB: We expect worldwide demand to increase.
DC: We expect weakness in sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no any mentioning about switching word positions (I added actual client's request in the comment section), I created the following procedure. I'm sure it can be optimized, but it works well for the client. Please note that text_to_vector procedure is defined in the original question text. I hope my post will be helpful for somebody.

```
def Sim_MinEdit(file1, file2):
    s1 = file(Input_path+'/'+file1).read().replace('\n',' ')
    s2 = file(Input_path+'/'+file2).read().replace('\n',' ')
    dict1 = text_to_vector(s1)
    dict2 = text_to_vector(s2)
    dict_diff_1_2 = {k : dict2[k] for k in set(dict2) - set(dict1)}
    dict_diff_2_1 = {k : dict1[k] for k in set(dict1) - set(dict2)}
    dict_comm_1_2 = {k : abs(dict2[k] - dict1[k]) for k in 
    set(dict2).intersection(set(dict1))}
    numerator = sum(dict_diff_1_2.values()) + sum(dict_diff_2_1.values()) + 
    sum(dict_comm_1_2.values())
    denominator = sum(dict1.values()) + sum(dict2.values())
    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return 1 - (float(numerator) / denominator)
```